# £ sign encoding -help!

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

I have a simple update set php sql function on my site where I can update the prices in my database for products on the webpage.

I have set the collation for all text fields in mysql to utf8_unicode_ci, and included

```
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8'/>
```

in all my pages. When I submit the edit button however, if I enter £200 for example, in the database instead of `&pound;200` it enters `&Acirc;&pound;200`.

I have read through countless forums on the issue and dont know what more I need to do to get this working - also, most of the discussions are at least 3 years old. Is there any new function I might be able to use to get this very small, but very frustrating glitch fixed?!

Thanks
JD

Comment: Would it not be better to just store the numeric value then add the &pound; when viewing the price after it's been pulled from the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line of PHP code, immediately after connecting to the MySQL database:

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
```

Comment: tried this but still not working - I think I will have to adopt the advice of Eddie where I dont use any currency in the text updates....